# django view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, view

Here is my view :

```
def GeneralUserPictureChange(request, pk, username):
thumb = GeneralUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
if thumb.username == request.user:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GeneralUserPictureChangeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            thumb.thumbnail = form.cleaned_data['thumbnail']
            thumb.save()
            return redirect("user_profile", pk, username)
        else:
            return render_to_response("gnu_picture_change.html", {"form":form, "basic_info":thumb}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = GeneralUserPictureChangeForm()
    return render_to_response("gnu_picture_change.html", {"form":form, "basic_info":thumb}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I do this gives the error didnt return HttpResponse object. But when I remove the line
`if thumb.username == request.user:` and continue with proper indentation it dont gives the error..

Need help ...

Comment: What happens when `if thumb.username == request.user:` is true and the code goes in that direction?

Comment: The question is what happens when the if is false, there is no return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing an `username` **field** and an `user` **object** here:

```
if thumb.username == request.user:
```

- `thumb.username` probably return a *string* like `'JohnDoe'`
- `request.user` return a object like:  `<User: johndoe>`

*So the `if` seems to be false **ALLWAYS***

To fix this, you should do:

```
if thumb.username == request.user.username:
```

- What happen if the first condition is false ? You need an alternative return, same indent as the `if thumb.username...`

---

**You're getting the None instead of a HttpResponse, because you don't have a return in case the first `if` is false**

```
def GeneralUserPictureChange(request, pk, username):
thumb = GeneralUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
if thumb.username == request.user:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GeneralUserPictureChangeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            thumb.thumbnail = form.cleaned_data['thumbnail']
            thumb.save()
            return redirect("user_profile", pk, username)
        else:
            return render_to_response("gnu_picture_change.html", {"form":form, "basic_info":thumb}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = GeneralUserPictureChangeForm()
    return render_to_response("gnu_picture_change.html", {"form":form, "basic_info":thumb}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# You need a return like this one, in case the first if is false
return render_to_response("gnu_picture_change.html", {"Error":'Not valid username'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: In the last return you should only return an error variable or intialize an empty form